# Aplicación android se detiene en teléfono pero no en emulador

Tags: android

Tengo una aplicación que se ejecuta bien desde la versión 4.x hasta la versión 5.x. Cuando hice el cambio a la versión 6.0, se detiene en los teléfonos con ésta versión pero no en el emulador.

Lo único que hice fue cambiar el targetSdkVersion 23. ¿Tengo que hacer algo más, donde está el problema?

Esta es la configuración:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.ta"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.5.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')

    compile files('libs/usbsdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/jasypt-1.9.2.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.2.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
}
```

Comment: y cual es el error desplegado en el LogCat?

Comment: ami se me hace que no tiene actualizado el google play services en el celu, ojala tengamos el Log

Comment: Creo que pueden ser varias cosas, si definiste targetSdk 23, probablemente son los permisos. Pero para asegurarlo se debe tener el LogCat para saber que permiso requiere. Un desarrollador móvil android debe saber la importancia del LogCat para encontrar fácilmente el origen del problema. =)

Comment: @Elenasys: Desafortunadamente es una aplicación productiva, no puedo ver el LogCat, el usuario hizo un upgrade de la versión 5.0 a 6 en su teléfono. Seguido a esto no pudo ejecutar algunas acciones que ya venía realizando. Básicamente se trata que la aplicación lee la MAC del equipo y la envía a un Webservice. Ya vimos los permisos en el teléfono y todos están prendidos. Como lo dije en mi comentario inicial, en el emulador todo corre bien y sin problema. No sé si ésta versión de Android bloquea esa parte de la MAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hector, si aseguraron encender todos los permisos requeridos por la aplicación entonces definitivamente ese no es el problema.

He encontrado cual es el problema, de hecho desconocía este cambio.

> Para proporcionar a los usuarios una mayor protección de datos , a
>   partir de esta versión 6.0, Android elimina el acceso mediante
>   programación al identificador local del hardware del dispositivo para
>   aplicaciones utilizando el Wi-Fi y Bluetooth API .

Los métodos `WifiInfo.getMacAddress()` y `BluetoothAdapter.getAddress()` ahora retornan un valor constante:   `02:00:00:00:00:00.`

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id

Comment: Si gracias, justamente me prestaron un teléfono con esa versión y me doy cuenta del valor constante que ahora proporciona el método WifiInfo.getMacAddress(), ni modo a prepararnos para estos cambios. Gracias.

Comment: Gracias a tu pregunta ahora me doy cuenta de este problema ya que necesito la Mac Address en una aplicación, en fin a prepararnos...